# Failed to upload Azure Blob Storage in PHP

Tags: php, azure, azure-blob-storage

I use this [official Azure Blob Storage sample file](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-php?tabs=linux).

It shows how to upload `HelloWorld.txt`.
It is successfully uploaded. However, if the one point changes, for example `HelloWorld.txt` to `Hello.jpg`, it uploads 0 Byte file.

My code, phpQS.php is

```php
// Create blob client.
$blobClient = BlobRestProxy::createBlobService($connectionString);

$fileToUpload = "Hello.jpg";

if (!isset($_GET["Cleanup"])) {
    // Create container options object.
    $createContainerOptions = new CreateContainerOptions();

...

}
```

Could you tell me how to upload a file completely?

This is the output in Webbrowser (with HTML).

[image]

Azure Console is

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, I wrote the Japanese page. The English site is https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-blobs-php-quickstart.
Also, when you open it, please turn on the switch ("英語で読む").
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-php?tabs=linux.

Comment: I tried to do the same way with the URL, but it shows failed. The file "HelloWorld.txt" was uploaded as 0 Byte file if I change the content.

Comment: The way I tried

1. get the file with "git clone https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-blobs-php-quickstart.git"
2. Get the keys from azure portal. (In to the Azure portal go to your storage account.
In the Settings section of the storage account overview, select Access keys to display your account access keys and connection string.
Note the name of your storage account, which you'll need for authorization.
Find the Key value under key1, and select Copy to copy the account key.)

3. Configure my storage connection (export ACCOUNT_NAME=<myname>
export ACCOUNT_KEY=<mykey>)

Comment: 3. Configure your environment
Take the folder from your local git folder and place it in a directory served by your PHP server. Then, open a command prompt scoped to that same directory and enter: php composer.phar install

Comment: But it uploads as 0 Byte file.

Comment: know nothing about php but I think these two links are helpful to fit your needs. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41682393/simple-php-curl-file-upload-to-azure-storage-blob) and (https://github.com/kaijaeger/php-azure-blob-upload)

Comment: If you could edit your post to include a transcription of the Webbrowser's answers output as text instead of only an image it would be good, because that way the message would show up on search engines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample project has issue, that is why, it doesn't work.
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-blobs-php-quickstart/issues/6