# Get azure blob files from inside Sub Directories using php

Tags: php, azure, curl, azure-storage, azure-storage-files

I want trying to get file from blob storage. I got successfully from blob storage without subdirectory but when I am trying to get files from inside  subdirectory then it doesn't work. In subdirectory case I use `$blobName like that test/1.png` where test is folder name and 1.jpg file name.

```
<?php

$storageAccount = 'XXXXXXX';
$containerName = 'XXXXXXXX';
$blobName = 'test/1.png';
$account_key = 'XXXXXXXXXX';

$date = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T');
$version = "2019-12-12";

$stringtosign = "GET\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-date:". $date . "\nx-ms-version:".$version."\n/".$storageAccount."/".$containerName."/".$blobName;
$signature = 'SharedKey'.' '.$storageAccount.':'.base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $stringtosign, base64_decode($account_key), true));
echo "\n\n" . $signature;

$header = array (
    "x-ms-date: " . $date,       
    "x-ms-version: " . $version,       
    "Authorization: " . $signature
);

$url="https://$storageAccount.blob.core.windows.net/$containerName/$blobName";
$ch = curl_init ();
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET' );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_exec ( $ch );
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo "\n\n" . $result;

if(curl_errno($ch)){
    throw new Exception(curl_error($ch));
}

file_put_contents('D://demo//downloaded.txt', $result); // save the string to a file

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: How's going? Has your issue been solved ?

Comment: @StanleyGong thanks but it is not resolved yet. Can it be any permission issue?

Comment: Not sure the root reason, it works for me with no problem. If this issue still exists, I think you can try to use storage blob PHP SDK to download files , you can find demo code here:https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/5dc75923f11042bca5b3cb6a16c82f3d104002cd/samples/BlobSamples.php#L359

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your code on my side but seems your code is all right, I can download my .jpg file which inside some subdirectory from the storage container:
[image]

Result:
[image]

I noticed in your code, you are downloading `.png file` content into a `.txt file` :

```
file_put_contents('D://demo//downloaded.txt', $result);
```

Maybe this is the reason that you did not get the excepted result.

Comment: please can you refer any link for directory listing from Azure blob storage?

Comment: @Martin see here : https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-blobs-php-quickstart/blob/master/phpQS.php#L102 You can also find other code samples in this project

Comment: can I do blob directory listing using simple php curl method like [Simple PHP cURL file upload to Azure storage blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41682393/simple-php-curl-file-upload-to-azure-storage-blob)

Comment: @Martin I see, could you pls open another question and let me know the link I'll provide you with code in that question.

Comment: can I download folder from azure blob storage using above php code which is not compressed in any format like .zip?

Comment: @NirdeshKumawat, Yes, you can use the way in a loop to download blobs in a directory

Comment: Please can you take a look on this post [Download a folder from azure blob storage which is not compressed in any format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67816970/download-a-folder-from-azure-blob-storage-which-is-not-compressed-in-any-format)