# Download a folder from azure blob storage which is not compressed in any format

Tags: php, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to download a folder which is not compressed in any format like .zip,7-zip. I took code from [Get azure blob files from inside Sub Directories using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65072219/get-azure-blob-files-from-inside-sub-directories-using-php/65083801?noredirect=1#comment119868807_65083801).

My Folder structure on azure blob storage like that `parentFolder>childFolder>1.pdf,2.pdf,3.pdf`.

I am trying to download `childFolder`. I am using below code But I am getting error `BlobNotFoundThe specified blob does not exist.`

```
<?php

$storageAccount = 'XXXXXXX';
$containerName = 'XXXXXXX';
$blobName = 'parentFolder/childFolder';
$account_key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

$date = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T');
$version = "2019-12-12";

$stringtosign = "GET\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-date:". $date . "\nx-ms-version:".$version."\n/".$storageAccount."/".$containerName."/".$blobName;
$signature = 'SharedKey'.' '.$storageAccount.':'.base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $stringtosign, base64_decode($account_key), true));
echo "\n\n" . $signature;

$header = array (
    "x-ms-date: " . $date,       
    "x-ms-version: " . $version,       
    "Authorization: " . $signature
);

$url="https://$storageAccount.blob.core.windows.net/$containerName/$blobName";
$ch = curl_init ();
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET' );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_exec ( $ch );
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo "\n\n" . $result;

if(curl_errno($ch)){
    throw new Exception(curl_error($ch));
}

file_put_contents('C://demo//childFolder', $result); // save the string to a file

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you have written. The information you provided is not sufficient to provide an answer unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try the code below that using `sasToken` and `cURL` to download all blobs under a folder:

```
<?php 

function generateSharedAccessSignature($accountName, 
    $storageKey, 
    $signedPermissions, 
    $signedService, 
    $signedResourceType, 
    $signedStart, 
    $signedExpiry, 
    $signedIP, 
    $signedProtocol, 
    $signedVersion){

    if(empty($accountName)){
        trigger_error("The account name is required.");
        return;
    }

    if(empty($storageKey)){
        trigger_error("The account key is required.");
        return;
    }

    if(empty($signedPermissions)){
        trigger_error("The permissions are required.");
        return;
    }

    if(empty($signedService)){
        trigger_error("The services are required.");
        return;
    }

    if(empty($signedResourceType)){
        trigger_error("The resource types are required.");
        return;
    }

    if(empty($signedExpiry)){
        trigger_error("The expiration time is required.");
        return;
    }

    if(empty($signedVersion)){
        trigger_error("The service version is required.");
        return;
    }
    // generate the string to sign
    $_toSign = urldecode($accountName) . "\n" . 
            urldecode($signedPermissions) . "\n" . 
            urldecode($signedService) . "\n" . 
            urldecode($signedResourceType) . "\n" . 
            urldecode($signedStart) . "\n" .
            urldecode($signedExpiry) . "\n" .
            urldecode($signedIP) . "\n" .
            urldecode($signedProtocol) . "\n" .
            urldecode($signedVersion) . "\n";

    // sign the string using hmac sha256 and get a base64 encoded version_compare
    $_signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", utf8_encode($_toSign), base64_decode($storageKey), true));

    return $_signature;
}

$key= "";
$storageAccount = "";
$containerName = "";
$directoryName = ""; 
$destDir = "d:/temp/";

$_signedPermissions = "rl";  //read and list permission
$_signedService = "b";       // for blob service
$_signedResourceType = "oc";  //only for access container  and object
$_signedStart = "2021-05-31T00:00:00Z";  //sas token start time
$_signedExpiry = "2021-06-10T00:00:00Z"; //sas token expairy time
$_signedIP = NULL;     // no IP limit
$_signedProtocol = "https";
$_signedVersion = "2020-02-10";

$_signature = generateSharedAccessSignature($storageAccount, 
    $key, 
    $_signedPermissions, 
    $_signedService, 
    $_signedResourceType, 
    $_signedStart, 
    $_signedExpiry, 
    $_signedIP, 
    $_signedProtocol, 
    $_signedVersion);

$sig = urlencode($_signature);

$sasToken = "sp=$_signedPermissions&srt=$_signedResourceType&ss=$_signedService&st=$_signedStart&se=$_signedExpiry&sv=$_signedVersion&spr=$_signedProtocol&sig=$sig";

$destinationURL = "https://$storageAccount.blob.core.windows.net/$containerName?restype=container&comp=list&prefix=$directoryName&$sasToken";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $destinationURL);

$content = curl_exec($ch);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($content);


foreach ($xml->Blobs->Blob as $i) {
    $url ="https://$storageAccount.blob.core.windows.net/$containerName/$i->Name";

    //Use basename() function to return the base name of file 
   $file_name = $destDir.basename($url)  ;
    
    //Use file_get_contents() function to get the file
    //from url and use file_put_contents() function to
    //save the file by using base name
    if(file_put_contents( $file_name,file_get_contents($url."?".$sasToken ))) {
        echo "$url:File downloaded successfully\n";
    }
    else {
        echo "File downloading failed.";
    }
}

?>
```

I have tested on my side, see result below:
my blobs :
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your approach will not work because the folders in Azure Blob Storage are not real folders. They are virtual folders. Your blob names are `parentFolder/childFolder/1.pdf` and so on.

To download blobs from a virtual folder, here's what you would need to do:

1. List blobs in your blob container. Since you only want to download blobs from `parentFolder/childFolder`, you will have to do `prefix` search. That will list all the blobs in the desired folder.
2. Once you have the list, then you can download each blob from that list.

Unfortunately I am not that much knowledgeable about PHP thus I am only giving you some guidance (and not code).

I would also recommend using `Azure Storage SDK for PHP` instead of consuming the REST API directly. That will make your job much easier. You can find more information about the SDK here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php.