# How to upload files directly to azure container?

Tags: php, azure, curl, azure-blob-storage

I am using a solution from this post - [Simple PHP cURL file upload to Azure storage blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41682393/simple-php-curl-file-upload-to-azure-storage-blob#_=)_

It is working but when I upload multiple files at the same time, then I am receiving this error -

```
LibreSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 104
```

I also tried adding **UserAgent** in headers as well as Curl (**CURLOPT_USERAGENT**), but the error still persists.

How can I solve this error?

**Note**: I am using PHP 5.6 so the azure library doesn't support this.

Comment: _"I am using PHP 5.6 so the azure library doesn't support this"_ <-- So if it's not supported why don't you update to something that isn't 8 years out-of-date... and will presumably work?

Comment: The web app on which I am working is using PHP 5.6 so right now updating PHP isn't an option for me that's the reason I am not using Azure Library. When I use PHP CURL to upload files, it gives the error that I mentioned earlier.

Comment: Is this on Windows or Linux? What version of `LibreSSL` is in your PHP environment? (you can find out by checking `phpinfo();`).

Comment: It's linux and LibreSSL isn't showing on phpinfo(). I am not aware of LibreSSL.
Using CURL to upload files in Azure works, but the LibreSSL error occurs sometimes and when re-trying it uploads again.