# Upload to Azure Blob Storage via REST API with PHP

Tags: php, azure, curl, azure-blob-storage

I am having trouble to upload an image. Please, see my code below. I really don't know what's wrong. Dies somebody do? Can you correct it, PLEASE? I have this error:

Result:

```
AuthenticationFailedServer failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.

RequestId: <Request ID> Time:2023-04-13T20:31:58.4450928Z

The MAC signature found in the HTTP request '...' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign:
'PUT

11746

image/png






x-ms-blob-cache-control:max-age=259200
x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob
x-ms-date:Thu, 13 Apr 2023 20:31:58 GMT
x-ms-version:2017-04-17
/<storage account>/<container name>/<blob name>'.
```

Here is the code:

```
function upload_blob(
    $file_to_upload,
    $blob_name // "image.png"
){
    $access_key = "<Access key>";
    $storage_account = "<Storage account>";
    $container_name = "<Container name>";
    $destination_url = "https://$storage_account.blob.core.windows.net/$container_name/$blob_name";
    $mime_type = mime_content_type($file_to_upload);
    $file_handle = fopen($file_to_upload, "r");
    $current_date = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s T", time());
    $file_length = filesize($file_to_upload);

    $header_resource = "x-ms-blob-cache-control:max-age=2592000\nx-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob\nx-ms-date:$current_date\nx-ms-version:2017-04-17";
    $url_resource = "/$storage_account/$container_name/$blob_name";

    $str_to_sign = "PUT\n\n\n$file_length\n\n$mime_type\n\n\n\n\n\n\n$header_resource\n$url_resource";

    $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", urldecode(utf8_encode($str_to_sign)), base64_decode($access_key), true));
    $auth_header = "SharedKey $storage_account:$signature";

    $headers = [
        "Authorization: " . $auth_header,
        "x-ms-blob-cache-control: max-age=259200",
        "x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob",
        "x-ms-date: " . $current_date,
        "x-ms-version: 2017-04-17",
        "Content-Type: $mime_type",
        "Content-Length: " . $file_length
    ];

    $curl_handle = curl_init($destination_url);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_INFILE, $file_handle);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, $file_length);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, true);
    $result = curl_exec($curl_handle);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r("Result:");
    print_r($result);
    print_r("============================================================");
    echo "</pre>";

    curl_close($curl_handle);
}
```

Thank you in advance...

I keep getting this error.

Comment: I guess you should read [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/the-mac-signature-found-in-the-http-request-xxxx-is-not-the-same/ba-p/3293726) for more information.

Comment: Thank's!! And this worked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41682393/simple-php-curl-file-upload-to-azure-storage-blob